# Echo from a database to HTML

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm trying to get a database entry into HTML but I'm having trouble. I've tried searching this site for help but unfortunately it's giving me even more errors. 
This one in particular isn't an error, it just puts out a wrong thing.

```
    <?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM maincontent";
        $result=mysql_query($query);

        echo $result;
    ?>
```

The result it's giving me is "Resource ID #4" - I have no such entry in the database table.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I'm pretty sure you can see that I'm new to PHP since this must be one of the easiest questions ever.

Answer (score 6):

You need to fetch the array and loop through it...

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM maincontent";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         echo $row[0];
    }
```

But you really shouldn't be using the deprecated mysql_* functions, instead use PDO...
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Here it is with PDO... in the future you should definitely learn and use PDO instead.

```
//Your connection data...
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);

// Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM maincontent";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Parse returned data, and display them
 while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row[0];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful! It echo-ed the ID instead of the needed text but it was an easy fix.

Comment: obviously he is at the beggining of coding, it is too early for PDO now

Comment: It's never too early to learn the right way to do things. Mysql_ is deprecated. It's not harder to use PDO than mysql_

Answer (score 1):

Your code only queries the database without fetching the data from the db.

To fetch the data you can complete your code like:

```
<?php
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
{
   echo $rows['database_column_here'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some has already pointed out the error in your code and provided a PDO example, together with the reason why you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. To these reasons I'd like to add that you're more vulnerable to mysql injections and, also, I'd like to post the code to do the same thing with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Although using PDO will give you more flexibility, mysqli may be the preferred approach if you need to switch quickly from `mysql_*`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM maincontent");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
printf ("%s \n", $row["COLUMN_NAME"]);

$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

I hope this might help in your decision. [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will also help.